# Why is the Monster group called that?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, terminology, math-history

This is a bit of a soft question, but why is the Monster group called that? Does it have any connection with monster models in model theory? I would be interested to learn who came up with that terminology.

Comment: My understanding is that it's because of its order.

Comment: Because it's big.

Comment: Because it’s very very big.

Comment: *Monstrously* big, one might even say.

Comment: The name is of course due to John Conway.

Comment: [John Horton Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway) to be precise.

Comment: The only connection to monster models is that both are called "monsters" because of their large size.